# The api route users/userId/{userId} needs to be changed to users/?id=abc

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

API route needs to be changed as I want to take the id as a parameter.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const authenticate = require("../middlewares/authenticate");
const authorizeRoles = require("../middlewares/authorizeRoles");
const users = require("../controllers/users");
const { SUPERUSER } = require("../constants/roles");
const userValidator = require("../middlewares/validators/user");
const { upload } = require("../utils/multer");
const { getUserBadges } = require("../controllers/badges");

router.post("/verify", authenticate, users.verifyUser);
router.get("/userId/:userId", users.getUserById);
router.patch("/self", authenticate, userValidator.updateUser, users.updateSelf);
router.get("/", authenticate, userValidator.getUsers, users.getUsers);
router.get("/self", authenticate, users.getSelfDetails);
router.get("/isUsernameAvailable/:username", authenticate, users.getUsernameAvailabilty);
router.get("/chaincode", authenticate, users.generateChaincode);
router.get("/:username", users.getUser);
router.get("/:userId/intro", authenticate, authorizeRoles([SUPERUSER]), users.getUserIntro);
router.put("/self/intro", authenticate, userValidator.validateJoinData, users.addUserIntro);
router.get("/:id/skills", users.getUserSkills);
router.get("/:id/badges", getUserBadges);

// upload.single('profile') -> multer inmemory storage of file for type multipart/form-data
router.post("/picture", authenticate, upload.single("profile"), users.postUserPicture);
router.patch("/profileURL", authenticate, userValidator.updateProfileURL, users.profileURL);
router.patch("/rejectDiff", authenticate, authorizeRoles([SUPERUSER]), users.rejectProfileDiff);
router.patch("/:userId", authenticate, authorizeRoles([SUPERUSER]), users.updateUser);
router.get("/suggestedUsers/:skillId", authenticate, authorizeRoles([SUPERUSER]), users.getSuggestedUsers);

module.exports = router;
```

The api route users/userId/{userId} needs to be changed to users/?id=abc , as this doesn't follow API designing rules.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @Alan To change the api route users/userId/{userId} to users/?id=abc. router.get("/userId/:userId", users.getUserById) Is this right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express cannot route based on query string so you'll need custom middleware to decide which handlers to call based on the request.

- `/users` -> `authenticate, userValidator.getUsers, users.getUsers`
- `/users?id=abc` -> `users.getUserById`

For example

```js
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.query.id) {
    // handle user ID request
    req.params.userId = req.query.id; // so you don't need to change getUserById
    return users.getUserById(req, res, next);
  }
  
  next(); // otherwise, forward to the remaining middleware
}, authenticate, userValidator.getUsers, users.getUsers);
```